# Twitter bootstrap with Django 1.5

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate Twitter bootstrap with my django application. In settings.py, I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/path/to/my/projects/templates/static/",
)
```

Under the `static` folder, there are 3 folders namely, **css, img and js** and all the bootstrap files have been copied into it as is.

My template looks like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-responsive.css' %}" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 

        <title>Test App</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">  
            <div class="navbar-inner">  
                <div class="container">  
                    <ul class="nav">  
                        <li class="active">  
                            <a class="brand" href="#">TEST APP</a>  
                        </li>  
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
                    </ul> 
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>
```

How ever, when I run the development server, I get a basic html page with no change and no css applied.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you working on windows or mac or linux, and what is your IDE?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - Fedora 19 and Eclipse with Pydev

Comment: Then take a look at the code I showed you. That should solve your problems.

Comment: Do you have Django configured to serve static files for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `static` folder is immediately underneath your Application root, this is a method that you could use to bullet-proof static file template rendering on all OSs.

```
import os

def replace(path):
    assert isinstance(path, str)
    return path.replace('\\', os.sep)


def here(*args):
    return replace(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *args)))


BASE_DIR = here('..')


def root(*args):
    return replace(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, *args)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (root('static'),)
```